# Error with newrelic and zope

Tags: python, plone, newrelic, zope

I'm trying to configure newrelic with zope but it is returning the error:

# bin/newrelic-admin run-python bin/zeoserver fg

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/zeoserver", line 22, in <module>
import plone.recipe.zeoserver.ctl
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.recipe.zeoserver-1.2.6-py2.7.egg/plone/recipe/zeoserver/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import zc.recipe.egg
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/zc/recipe/egg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from zc.recipe.egg.egg import Egg, Scripts, Eggs
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/zc/recipe/egg/egg.py", line 21, in <module>
    import zc.buildout.easy_install
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.5-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 81, in <module>
    pkg_resources.Requirement.parse('zc.buildout')).location,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'location'
```

Does anyone know what can it be pls?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading some of your packages. I suspect setuptools, buildout or zc.recipe.egg!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved adding the below code in a __init__.py from application:

```
import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize('path/of/newrelic.ini')
```

And execute the application without the command "newrelic-admin run-python".

Newrelic worked but with limitations because don't have official support yet.